# How to export variable from function in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I define a variable inside a function I can not use it outside.

I tried to define a variable in within `NgOnInit` and it does not work either.

My code:

```js
addLink() {
    if(
      this.product.name !== '' && 
      this.product.price !== 0 && 
      this.product.instaURL !== '') {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            let uid = user.uid;
            console.log(uid)  //THIS WORK
          }
        });      
      console.log(uid); //THIS DONT WORK
      this.productService.addProduct(this.product);      
      this.product = {} as Product;
    }
  }
```

The error I get:

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'uid'.

Comment: you should use the Angular tag here

Comment: @BrunoCicerchia check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/56996590/5042169 It solves TypeError: Cannot set property 'uid' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `uid` is a block scope variable. You can learn more about variable scoping from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2). Also you can do the following changes in your code to get `uid` outside of `if` condition

```
addLink() {
    let uid;
    if(this.product.name !== '' && this.product.price !== 0 && this.product.instaURL !== '') {
     firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
       if (user) {
         uid = user.uid;
         console.log(uid)  //THIS WORK
       }
     });      
    console.log(uid); //THIS WILL WORK TOO
    this.productService.addProduct(this.product);      
    this.product = {} as Product;
 }
}
```

Comment: Now i dont have any error but "uid" in the console.log outside the function is undefined

Comment: yes because `uid` variable is not globally defined. You need to add the variable before constructor to make it global just like `product` variable in your code

Comment: Please try the answer given by [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9518388/dan-gorman). This is exactly what you need

Comment: Throw this error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'uid' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property 'uid' of undefined

Comment: Yes because you're using `function` keyword. You need to use fat arrow functions to get `this` inside a function. Your `firebase` code will looks like this

   `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=> {
          if (user) {
            this.uid = user.uid;
            console.log(this.uid) 
          }
        }); `

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the scope of variables declared as `let` are limited by block they are defined, to make use of it you simply declare it outside your function scope.

```
addLink() {
if(
  this.product.name !== '' && 
  this.product.price !== 0 && 
  this.product.instaURL !== '') {
    let uid;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        uid = user.uid;
        console.log(uid)  //THIS WORK
      }
    });      
  console.log(uid); //THIS ALSO WORKS ;)
  this.productService.addProduct(this.product);      
  this.product = {} as Product;
}
```

}

Comment: I would strongly discourage to use var when it comes to typescript/angular,  let is provided keeping in mind the scope and non hoisting, with var we will end up mixing things.

Comment: I did not realized this was running in Typescript, sorry for that.

Comment: No problem, it happens.. it's just about being more careful as we might end up providing some wrong info sometimes

Answer (score 0):

The code above is functioning as it should. With a 'let' inside of a function it is only temporary. Instead create a variable right after declaring the class:

```
export class FooBatComponent implements OnInit {
uid: number;

...

addLink() {
    if(
      this.product.name !== '' && 
      this.product.price !== 0 && 
      this.product.instaURL !== '') {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            this.uid = user.uid;
            console.log(this.uid)  
          }
        });      
      this.productService.addProduct(this.product);      
      this.product = {} as Product;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Throw this error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'uid' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'uid' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You need to first understand the scope thing, whenever you declare a variable with let inside a block that becomes block level scope and is available only inside that block , define things at higher level scope to use that variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function scope issue. You have to declare `let uid` outside the callback function.

And, you need to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to keep this in the function context to prevent `Cannot set property 'uid' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property 'uid' of undefined` error.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.uid = user.uid;
    console.log(this.uid)  
  }
});
```

OR

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    this.uid = user.uid;
    console.log(this.uid)  
  }
}.bind(this));
```

Read more on [mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

> let allows you to declare variables that are limited to a scope of a block statement, or expression on which it is used

```js
export class FooBatComponent implements OnInit {
uid: number;

...

addLink() {
  if (this.product.name !== '' && 
    this.product.price !== 0 && 
    this.product.instaURL !== '') {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          this.uid = user.uid;
          console.log(this.uid)  
        }
      });      
      console.log(this.uid);
      this.productService.addProduct(this.product);      
      this.product = {} as Product;
   }
}
```